# Force protected constructor in PHP

Tags: php, constructor, interface, abstract-class

I'm wondering if it is possible in PHP to force a class to have its constructor be protected as part of a design pattern.

So far I've tried to implement it with interfaces and abstract classes but it doesn't seem to work. I want all of my Service classes to be Singletons and I achieve this (to some degree) by making the counstructor protected. How can I enforce this?

Comment: _I want all of my Service classes to be Singletons..._ Very bad/unwise idea...

Comment: use static method with a protected variable ?

Comment: @bub why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to make a constructor protected.

Here an example for singleton pattern:

```
<?php

class Test {

    private static $instance = null;

    protected function __construct()
    {
    }

    public static function getSingleton()
    {
        if (self::$instance === null) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }
}

// Does work
$test = Test::getSingleton();

// doesn't work
$test = new Test();
```

For "services" use a dependency injection container.
As example I use a simple container implementation, but there are a lot more.
http://container.thephpleague.com/2.x/getting-started/

```
<?php

interface ExampleServiceInterface {

}

class ImplementationA implements ExampleServiceInterface {

}

class ImplementationB implements ExampleServiceInterface {

}

$container = new League\Container\Container;

// add a service to the container
$container->share(ExampleServiceInterface::class, function() {
    $yourChoice = new ImplementationA();
    // configure some stuff? etc
    return $yourChoice;
});

// retrieve the service from the container
$service = $container->get(ExampleServiceInterface::class);

// somewhere else, you will get the same instance
$service = $container->get(ExampleServiceInterface::class);
```

Comment: I'm using just that pattern. However I'm looking for a way to force the pattern itself, so that only services of that pattern can be written. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Do you know containers? I will add a nice way to get it done

Comment: Thanks a lot, that looks very promising and a lot like what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

you can force it by throwing an exception?

```
final class Foo {
   private static $meMyself = null;
   protected function __construct() {

      if(!is_null(Foo::$meMyself)) {
         throw new \Exception("ouch. I'm seeing double");
      }
      // singleton init code
   }
}
```

but there against speaks: People who use it will probably have access to your methods/code and can just change it.